# I am creating an app for my drone, not working UDP

Tags: java, android

I am creating app that sends joystick data via UDP to my ESP32 at 192.168.4.1:1234 and whenever i try to send any data it crashes.

Crash Log:

```
2022-09-06 17:22:38.864 15388-15388/com.example.drnecontroller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.drnecontroller, PID: 15388
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1668)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
    at com.example.drnecontroller.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0(MainActivity.java:44)
    at com.example.drnecontroller.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

2022-09-06 17:22:38.911 393-393/? E/BpTransactionCompletedListener: Failed to transact (-32)

Client script:

```
package com.example.drnecontroller;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
        TextView IPAddrShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IPAddressShow);
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            try {
                int port = 1234;
                byte[] MSG;
                DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                MSG = "HELLO".getBytes();
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(MSG, MSG.length,IP,port);
                datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
                IPAddrShow.setText("Sent");
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned that i have "localhost" instead of "192.168.4.1" sorry, but that didn't solved my problem

Comment: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 0):

On android, you cannot use network from the UI thread.
All you have to do is to send your data from an other thread. I recommend using an executor.

For example by wrapping your code in a Runnable :

```
ExecutorService executor= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.submit(yourRunnable);
```

Comment: how do i pass param?
```code
    
Runnable sendUDP = () -> {
        
try {            
policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();            
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

socket.setBroadcast(true);
byte[] sendData = MSG.getBytes();
            
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.4.1"), 1234);
        } catch (SocketException | UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };```

Comment: Any variable declared "final" will be accessible from the Runnable.